# Can I put a deleted PSN account on a new PS3?

Tags: psn, hard-drive

So when I was living with my roommate he used my ps3 to download rockband songs onto a specific account which I basically let him use for his rockband needs. I recently moved out and once he gets some extra cash he will be buying a new ps3. I understand the account can move from one ps3 to the other just by logging in, but I was reading something on one of downloaded games that said if all the accounts that owned the software were deleted you could no longer play that game. So that got me thinking..

I'm planning on upgrading my hard drive but not sure if I should wait till he gets a ps3 and has the account tied to it or if it really doesn't matter. I think it might be awhile before he gets a ps3 so knowing if I could upgrade asap would be great.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by deleted, you mean have the account removed entirely from the PSN, then yes, I would think you could no longer play any downloaded game, or access any downloadable content.

However, if by deleted, you mean your PSN account is still intact, but you're replacing your hard drive so you have to add your account again to the new drive, I think it should be fine. The PSN should still have whatever games and content you've downloaded tied to your account on their servers. So, I would think that once you've logged in again using your new hard drive, you would be able to re-download all of your games.

Comment: cool, thank you. That was pretty much the answer in my head but I wanted a second opinion, so I threw it at the community and saw what stuck. Thanks again.

Comment: @stay - No problem. I hope it works out for you.